# Error en FullCanlendar v4.0 calendar.refetchEvents is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, ajax, fullcalendar

Estoy configurando un calendario con el plugin FullCalendar, en donde realizo una peticion AJAX. Pero no se refresca el calendario al insertar el Evento.

function enviarDatos(objeto) {

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{route('agenda.store')}}",
            data: objeto,
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(objeto);
                $('#modal').modal('hide');
              console.log(calendar);
              calendar.refetchEvents();

            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });


    }
```

Lo datos se envian de manera correcta, pero al ejecutarce la funcion success en el llamado al la instancia calendar.refetchEvents(); informa que no es una funcion, y por lo que figura en la documentación es una funcion que se encuentra en vigencia.

El llamando a los los script locales :

```
 <script src={{asset('fullcalendar/packages/core/main.js')}}></script>
<script src={{asset('fullcalendar/packages/daygrid/main.js')}}></script>
<script src={{asset('fullcalendar/packages/list/main.js')}}></script>
<script src={{asset('fullcalendar/packages/timegrid/main.js')}}></script>
<script src={{asset('fullcalendar/packages/interaction/main.js')}}></script>
```

Comment: En codepen he visto ejemplos, tal vez los encuentres interesantes para tu proyecto. Busca 'FullCalendar'

Comment: Me meto en la web oficial y abajo del todo leo esto: `Beyond dragging an event to a different time/day, you cannot change an event's name or other associated data. It is up to you to add this functionality through FullCalendar's API.`Lo cual me hace pensar que sin usar su API tal vez no puedas actualizar los datos que muestra tu calendario y por tanto no se puedan ver cambios.

Comment: yo trataría de usar los métodos, remove y add relacionados con los events. Si quiero actualizar mis eventos en el calendario pues eliminaría los que coincidieran en tiempo con los nuevos y después añadiría los nuevos con el método add. Aunque sinceramente espero que haya un método al que pueda recurrir sin tener que hacerme mi propia función basada en los métodos mencionados.